# rails rspec testing nested create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec

Can someone please help me to figure out how to test nested create action.

**Controller.rb**

```
def create
  @itemline = V1::ItemLine.new(:net_price => params[:net_price])
  @v1_product = @itemline.build_product(v1_product_params)
  @v1_product.save
end

def v1_product_params
  params.require(:v1_product).permit(:name, :net_price, :item_line => [:quantity, :net_price])
end
```

**Controller_spec.rb**

```
describe "with valid params" do
  it "creates a new V1::Product" do
    expect {
      post :create, :v1_product => {name: "test", net_price: 10, item_line_id: 1 }, token: @user.api_key.token
    }.to change(V1::Product, :count).by(1)
    expect(V1::Product.last.name).to eq "test"
    expect(V1::Product.last.net_price).to eq 10
    expect(V1::Product.last.item_line_id).to eq 1  #FAILS
  end
```

It does create the product, but it doesn't build the V1::ItemLine.new. Can anyone see what is the problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your code

```
@itemline = V1::ItemLine.new(:net_price => params[:net_price])
```

is not correct, because :net_price is nested in :v1_product hash

```
params.require(:v1_product).permit(:name, :net_price, :item_line => [:quantity, :net_price])
```

Try

```
@itemline = V1::ItemLine.new(:net_price => params[:v1_product][:net_price])
```

Comment: Ohh, thats not it, I actually want to pass those params. and if the other exist they should over ride them on the build_product line. the problem is that, current test don't even create item line. ohh dear there was a mistake in the question. fixed it now.